# jQuery can't get elements parent which is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm creating pagination element with [Simple Pagination Plugin](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/).
 I want to get the parent of clicked pagination button.But when click event fires jquery can't get find parent of this element.Here's my code.I hope anyone can help.Thank you.

```
$(document).on('click','.page-link',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var page = href.split('-');
    var catalog = $(this).closest('div.page-changer').attr('data-catalog');
    alert(catalog)
  });
```

Here's HTML markup.

```
   <div class="page-changer col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-catalog="2">
   <div class=" col-md-8 paginate0 light-theme simple-pagination" >
    <ul>
     <li class="disabled"> 
        <span class="current prev">
         <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></span>
    </li>
   <li class="active">
     <span class="current">1</span>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#page-2" class="page-link">2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#page-2" class="page-link next">
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
     </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: share html mark up

Comment: it should work. add a closing tag div and try again

Comment: closing tag exists but not showing here.I don't now correctly  StackOverflow guide.

Comment: It is working, I just copy and paste your code into jsfiddle :)  check it please: https://jsfiddle.net/QMaster/8u22zo2q/

Comment: in my project <ul> and child elements creating while page loads.It alerts "undefined"

Comment: place it inside document . ready?

Comment: tried both but still alerts "undefined" :(

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax instead of your to bind event on dynamically generated elements in dom

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".page-link", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var page = href.split('-');
    var catalog = $(this).closest('div.page-changer').attr('data-catalog');
    alert(catalog)
});
```

Comment: what is the difference between using document and body?

Comment: Can you please give the structure that yu have right now to get the parent div. The dom element structure

Comment: I shared HTML markup above.$('body') not worked for me.Thank you for answer.

Comment: Please check my latest answer, it works here for me https://jsfiddle.net/xdouLdu2/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes doing things dynamic can be headache...
so it seems putting

```
    data-catalogid ="2" data-page="2"
```

like usage may be another approach.
Globally binding is good for dynamic DOM manipulation. I mean

```
     .change() vs .on
```

in this binding function work with elements data attributes may be less confusing.

```
    <div class="page-changer col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-catalog="2">
        <div class="col-md-8 paginate0 light-theme simple-pagination">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a data-catalog="2" data-page="2" href="#page-2" class="page-link next"> <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).on('click', 'a[data-page]', function () {
            console.log(" From Clicked Link" + " Catalog:" + $(this).data("catalog") + " Page:" + $(this).data("page"));
            console.log("From Page Changer (Parent) -> " + $(this).closest('.page-changer').data("catalog"));
        });
    </script>
```

You can add these to all links, data-catalog="2" data-page="2"

Comment: I'm really struggling :).

Comment: data-catalog attribute of anchors parent div.click event fires correctly but why it can't find parent div.

Comment: Edited answer... ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer but I changed case for that situation :).The problem was not about the selector.I saved this solution for future :)

Answer (score 0):

All are perfect in your code just move  e.preventDefault(); at bottom in your function

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".page-link", function() {

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var page = href.split('-');
    var catalog = $(this).closest('div.page-changer').attr('data-catalog');
    alert(catalog)
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: still alerts "undefined". May this problem be about the plugin.There also click event fires.